# How to share a Tensorflow Keras model with a Flask route function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, keras

Does tensorflow maintains its own internal global state, which is broken by loading the model in one function and trying to use it in another?

Using singleton for storing model:

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instances = {}

    def __new__(class_, *args, **kwargs):
        if class_ not in class_._instances:
            class_._instances[class_] = super(Singleton, class_).__new__(class_, *args, **kwargs)
        return class_._instances[class_]


class Context(Singleton):
    pass
```

When I do:

```
@app.route('/file', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            # filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            filename = file.filename
            filepath = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
            file.save(filepath)

            context = Context()
            if context.loaded:

                img = cv2.imread(filepath)
                img = cv2.resize(img, (96, 96))
                img = img.astype("float") / 255.0
                img = img_to_array(img)
                img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)

                classes = context.model.predict(img)

def api_run():
    context = Context()
    context.model = load_model('model.h5')
    context.loaded = True
```

I'm getting some error: `ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_1/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.`

However if I will move `context.model = load_model('model.h5')` inside `upload_file` function then everything will work. Why is that happening? How to store model for later use?

Comment: You should show us how you are actually executing this

Comment: @Karl I run python file which calls `api_run()` function and `@app` is flask thing

Comment: That tells me very little unfortunately. Show us an actual code example where you run this. Show us where it fails when you do it one way and where it succeeds when you do it another.

Comment: @Karl it's all in question, please provide what exactly is not clear, it works if line `context.model = load_model('model.h5')` move to function `upload_file` after line `context = Context()`

Comment: Two things to try (not sure they are actual). Use named layers in your model. Give a name to all its layers when creating it, so names like `dense_1/Softmax:0` don't have a chance to be wrong with bad indexing.  -- If your model was created joining parts of other models, like creating an extra `Input` and passing this input through an existing model, then you may try to use `existing_model.input` and `existing_model.output` instead of calling the model on a new input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Tensorflow in graph mode has its own internal global state.

You don't want to reload your model at every prediction, that's really inefficient.

The right strategy is to load the model at the start of your web app and then reference the global state.

Use a global variable for the model and graph and do something like this:

```py
loaded_model = None
graph = None

def load_model(export_path):

    # global variables
    global loaded_model
    global graph

    loaded_model = load_model('model.h5'))
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

then, in your prediction function you do:

```py
@app.route('/', methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.data

        with graph.as_default():
            probas = loaded_model.predict(data)
```

An complete short example for how to do this can be found [here](https://github.com/zerotodeeplearning/ztdl-5-day-bootcamp/blob/7b687fe2761bb5516e2ea239cb8339a0f8931208/day_5/model_serving/flask_serve_model.py).

Alternatively, if you use Tensorflow 2.0, which defaults to Eager mode, you have no graph and therefore no problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issue. Everything solved when

```
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
```

and then before loading model called

```
 K.clear_session()
```

Comment: ehm, on what moment? every time before use in `upload_file` ?

Comment: Now I see, maybe your suggestion  every time before use in upload_file will be more appropriate.

Comment: same: `ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_1/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.`

Comment: Can you just for try, load model at upload_file method with clear session at beginning?

Comment: everything works if I just load mode in upload_file method

Comment: That was my use-case with Flask and tf.  I load my model at route, model produce results and everything was fine... until another request appears, after second request model computation crashed(some node not element of this graph). Fix for me was clear session before model loading.